# Visual Studio 2013 Publish Profiles saving inconsistently

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, publish-profiles

When I modify an existing publish profile, Visual Studio 2013 Update 1 does not always save the corresponding pubxml file in the /Properties folder. I'm playing a constant game of modifying files until my changes are registered correctly in the file system.

For example, one publish profile that I edited and "saved" using the prompt has its pubxml file marked as delete. I suspect the profiles are cached and Visual Studio 2013 is not reflecting what's in the file system in real time.

The save prompt only shows up when I go to another profile or hit the publish button. It would be nice to have a save button that would force the pubxml files to show the latest.

Does anyone have a clear workaround this? I had a similar experience with web.config transformation in the same project and ended up editing the project file.

I'm certain this is not bound to the specific project I am currently dealing with as I see the same behavior in other projects. I never had this issue in Visual Studio 2010.

You'll not see this issue if you have just created new profiles. I am only seeing this behavior when I modify the existing profiles.

Comment: open VS as admin and try again... might be a file access issue.

Comment: It's possible that my Perforce Visual Studio Plugin is getting in the way. This could be an edge case for a small group of users.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and end-up here after goggling, did you find the fix?

Comment: @AbuHamzah are you using any source control? try checking out all the files in /Properties before editing any publish profiles. that seems to do the trick in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, I was able to delete the Profile in the VS GUI.
this is in VS 2013 Professional.
I clicked the Build menu  / Publish "yourSite"
Then on the Publish button was able to click it or right click it and then I could see the Manage button show up under the publish section. I clicked that, then was able to delete my original profile. then I created a new one.

I guess once you create a profile the manager button disappears.

Comment: It's just not saving consistently for me. I've 4-6 publish profiles in different solutions.